# post request with body Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, http-headers, alamofire

I am trying to post some data to the API, but I keep getting `Response status code was unacceptable: 404` error message.. I have checked, the `POST` parameters and `API Url` are all correct, example request works on the `postman` but it is not working on `Xcode`..

my `POST` request `Url` is in this format:    `{{API}}/postData/Id/block`.

my `POST` request function with `Alamofire` is as follows:

```
   func postData(token: String, id: String, category: String, completion: @escaping(_ data: DataTobePost) -> Void) {
        let header: HTTPHeaders = ["authorization": token]
        let parameter: Parameters = [
            "Id": id,
            "category": category ]
        
        Alamofire.request(API_Configurator.postData, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).validate().responseData(completionHandler: { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let val):
                do {
                    let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(DataTobePost.self, from: val)
                    completion(data)
                }catch {
                    print("[DataTobePost Catch Error while decoding response: \(error.localizedDescription)]")

                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("[DataTobePost Failure Error : \(error.localizedDescription)]")
            }
        })
    }
```

and the response is:

```
{
    "success": true
}
```

where am i going wrong, can anyone help through this. (I am quite new to `Alamofire`)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to check what is wrong.
If you got the 404 error it means 2 things:

1. Code was written correctly(it compiles)
2. Requested page does not exist (404 error)

I think you need to check your API_Configurator.postData.
Usually, it's something simple like extra characters like "//", " ", "."  etc.

Or the problem with API.
The best way to check API uses Postman